# Strange XmlSerializer behavior

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, invalidoperationexception

So i'm having some trouble deserializing an XML file.
I'm using the following struct.

```
[Serializable]
public struct GraphicsOptions
{
    public int Height;
    public int Width;
    public bool Fullscreen;
    public bool AntiAliasing;
    public int ClickResCount;
}
```

And the following code to Create,

```
public void CreateData()
{
    graphicsOptions.Height = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
    graphicsOptions.Width = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
    graphicsOptions.Fullscreen = graphics.IsFullScreen;
    graphicsOptions.AntiAliasing = graphics.PreferMultiSampling;
    graphicsOptions.ClickResCount = 1;
    dataStream = File.Create(SavegamePath);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GraphicsOptions));
    serializer.Serialize(dataStream, graphicsOptions);
    dataStream.Close();
}
```

Change and

```
private void ApplyChanges()
{
    graphicsOptions.Height = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
    graphicsOptions.Width = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
    graphicsOptions.Fullscreen = graphics.IsFullScreen;
    graphicsOptions.AntiAliasing = graphics.PreferMultiSampling;
    graphicsOptions.ClickResCount = clickCountResolution;
    dataStream = File.Open(SavegamePath, FileMode.Open);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GraphicsOptions));
    serializer.Serialize(dataStream, graphicsOptions);
    dataStream.Close();
}
```

Load the XML file

```
public void LoadData()
{
    dataStream = File.Open(SavegamePath, FileMode.Open);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GraphicsOptions));
    graphicsOptions = (GraphicsOptions)serializer.Deserialize(dataStream);
    dataStream.Close();
 }
```

Pretty standard stuff, except after the third time I apply the changes it decides to add 2 characters at the end of the file: `"s>"`.

I have no idea why it does this, but it makes the XML practically useless because I can't load the information into my **struct**.
Visual Studio is giving me an **InvalidOperationException** (I understand why it does this).

Any advice or ideas on how to prevent this from occuring or how to simply delete the 2 characters if it catches the exception?

Comment: It would really help if you'd just give us a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - which only needs to save the file, really.

Comment: did i give too much information or not enough? the program in question is made with the XNA framework, i can add the update logic, but it wont really give you any more information

Comment: A mixture - too much (i.e. some extraneous stuff) and not enough (not a short but complete program demonstrating the problem). XNA is *probably* irrelevant - but it would be easy to tell if you'd just create a short console app (not snippets, just a whole program) which shows the issue.

Comment: did you try dataStream.Flush() after every write operation?

Comment: good advice, i tried it but no cigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because your new file is short than it was previously. You should use `FileMode.Create` instead of `Open/OpenOrCreate`

So Your save function should look like this::

```
private void ApplyChanges()
{
    graphicsOptions.Height = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
    graphicsOptions.Width = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
    graphicsOptions.Fullscreen = graphics.IsFullScreen;
    graphicsOptions.AntiAliasing = graphics.PreferMultiSampling;
    graphicsOptions.ClickResCount = clickCountResolution;
    using(dataStream = File.Open(SavegamePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GraphicsOptions));
        serializer.Serialize(dataStream, graphicsOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give me that option

Comment: Sorry my mistake it's create, not write: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change the ApplyChanges() method to use another FileMode, like FileMode.Create. You can find the correct method below.

```
 private void ApplyChanges()
 {
    graphicsOptions.Height = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
    graphicsOptions.Width = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
    graphicsOptions.Fullscreen = graphics.IsFullScreen;
    graphicsOptions.AntiAliasing = graphics.PreferMultiSampling;
    graphicsOptions.ClickResCount = clickCountResolution;
    dataStream = File.Open(SavegamePath, FileMode.Create); // You can use FileMode.Truncate as well.
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GraphicsOptions));
    serializer.Serialize(dataStream, graphicsOptions);
    dataStream.Close();
  }
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx